# python- To predict time against a categorical variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, timedelta, arima

Let us consider I am having a data set in form of .log file.

[image]

Now can i predict how much will it take for a new job to complete by using ARIMA model?

I have seen many documentation in ARIMA model and only quantitative variable(like stock price,profit value) is predicted against time.
Is there any possibility to predict timedelta variable(hours_taken to complete one job) against job name?